# Make NSButton translucent

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsbutton, nsvisualeffectview

I have 2 NSButtons on a NSVisualEffectView. The first buttons image is the system NSEnterFullScreenTemplate image. The image on this first button is translucent.

On the second button I have an image that I imported in Assets.xcassets. On this second button the image is not translucent (it stays white).

How can I make this image also translucent?

Comment: Have you tried subclassing NSButton? Adding a subview - an NSVisualEffectView - that is the same size as the button?

Comment: Not yet, I figured since it works for the NSEnterFullScreenTemplate image I maybe missed something to get it to work with a custom image

Comment: Ok. One time I added a UITabBar to a view and found the blur over a collection view went from blurring an image to all gray. (That's when I discovered the benefits of CoreImage!) It probably wouldn't take much time to implement my suggestion - but the downside is only buttons have the blur. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `template` setting on `NSImage`:

`button.image.isTemplate = true`

Comment: thanks a lot that worked! Is this also possible for NSTextField?

Comment: `NSTextField` can be made vibrant by setting the `textColor` to `NSColor.labelColor` or `NSColor.secondaryLabelColor`.

For more information on how to achieve vibrancy with `NSVisualEffectView`, see the WWDC 2014 Session 220: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/220/